# Caught between willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath and didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the tableView, `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` is triggered on a very slight cell swipe to move into editing mode.  The gesture is not pulled to the left long enough to have the cell stay at the left, while the 3 `UITableViewRowAction` buttons are exposed.  Instead, the cell slides back to the right.  However,`didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` is not triggered automatically.  Only a following touch gesture will trigger that method. Why does `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` not trigger if the cell slides back to the right?  How do I pick up when the gesture has ended and/or the cell has returned to the normal state aligned to the right?

Or to put it in another way. `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` was fired and changed the state of my screen to the editing state.  However, since the editing stage was never reached, I need to change the screen state back to the non-editing state. `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` would do that but it is not be called until another touch, and that would leave the user confused.  Is there another indicator, maybe in `UIControl` that fires that I can use?

More info: the UITableViewRowAction buttons are subclassed based on the following repo: https://github.com/benguild/BGTableViewRowActionWithImage.  Although tests with standard `UITableViewRowAction` did not solve the problem.

Comment: any example or visual?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, I think you're asking for more information than the delegate provides.   It tells you *only* that the gesture started and that editing ended; nothing about the state of the animations in between.

Comment: Less about the state of animations, and more that the editing stage was never reached @danh ...yet `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` was fired and changed the state of my screen, and now I need to change it back since `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` was not called.

Comment: I think you and the SDK disagree about what constitutes the editing state (and what constitutes sufficient notice, thereof).  I'm with you, but it looks like Apple isn't.

Comment: Technically you can also listen to `editing` changes on every `UITableViewCell` but I am not sure it would make a difference.

Comment: This looks like a hole in the API. I'd [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thank you @ZevEisenberg! Do you think there may be something related to me using a subclass of UITableViewRowAction?

Comment: I doubt it, but that's easy to test - just stop using a subclass and see what happens. But to me, it just doesn't look like there's a delegate method in the API that does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even thou this is a iOS bug, i found a workaround.

In your cell, add the following code:

```
@interface UITableViewCell () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isShowingDeleteConfirmationMask;
@end

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecongizer:)];
    self.panRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:self.panRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)panGestureRecongizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            [self refreshCellState];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
            [self refreshCellState];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];

    if (state == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask) {
        self.isShowingDeleteConfirmationMask = NO;
    } else if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)  {
        self.isShowingDeleteConfirmationMask = YES;
    }
}

- (void)refreshCellState
{
     double delayInSeconds = 1.0; // one second should be enough for animationt to complete
     dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
     dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         BOOL deleteViewExists = NO;
         for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
             // There is a iOS bug where swiping left on cell to show delete button would not trigger default state
             // if you don't swipe pass delete button
             if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) {
                 deleteViewExists = YES;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if (!deleteViewExists && [self isEditing] && self.isShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
             if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cellDidEndEditing:)]) {
                 [self.delegate cellDidEndEditing:self];
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

In your view controller,

```
- (void)cellDidEndEditing:(nonnull LPToteItemTableViewCell *)cell
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO];
}
```